# Apple wired keyboard issue

Tags: keyboard, apple, apple-keyboard

I have been using an Apple wired keyboard with my 16.04 distro without any problems many months now. Since yesterday, I have unplugged this keyboard and plugged in my Razer keyboard. When I plugged the Apple keyboard back in, some keys stopped working (b and p for example).

I have tried:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

After reboot, still no luck.

I have also tried setting Num lock on or off using the other keyboard. Still no luck.

Any solutions to bring it back to the previous working state before I plugged in the Razer keyboard will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Alex